# Pinescript's / TradingView's Question: Conditional Exit for a Single Trade

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
leftBars = input(4)
rightBars = input(2)
swh = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
swl = ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)
swh_cond = not na(swh)
hprice = 0.0
hprice := swh_cond ? swh : hprice[1]
le = false
le := swh_cond ? true : (le[1] and high > hprice ? false : le[1])
if (le)
    strategy.entry("PivRevLE", strategy.long, comment="PivRevLE", stop=hprice + syminfo.mintick)
swl_cond = not na(swl)
lprice = 0.0
lprice := swl_cond ? swl : lprice[1]
se = false
se := swl_cond ? true : (se[1] and low < lprice ? false : se[1])
if (se)
    strategy.entry("PivRevSE", strategy.short, comment="PivRevSE", stop=lprice - syminfo.mintick)
```

I need your assistance with my code snippet above.

In this TradingView's strategy, it will only exit a trade if the opposite direction of entry is triggered.I'm trying to achieve the following:

Any position to exit at 40 ticks loss or when the opposite direction of entry is triggered. Whichever comes first.

Ideally, I want to use this strategy but only willing to have a maximum loss of 40 ticks per trade.

I've tested so many possibilities but it just doesn't turn out as what I want to achieve.

Example in the "What did you try and what were you expecting?" section

```
if inTradeWindow
    if (le)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long", stop=hprice + syminfo.mintick, loss=40 * syminfo.mintick, tp=hprice + syminfo.mintick)
    if (se)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="Short", stop=lprice - syminfo.mintick, loss=40 * syminfo.mintick, tp=lprice - syminfo.mintick)
```

```
if inTradeWindow
    if (le)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long", stop=longStop)
        // Exit conditions for long entry
        strategy.exit("LongExitAtStop", from_entry="Long", stop=longStop)
        strategy.exit("LongExitAtLoss", from_entry="Long", loss=40 * syminfo.mintick)

    if (se)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="Short", stop=shortStop)
        // Exit conditions for short entry
        strategy.exit("ShortExitAtStop", from_entry="Short", stop=shortStop)
        strategy.exit("ShortExitAtLoss", from_entry="Short", loss=40 * syminfo.mintick)
```

```
// Entry conditions
if (le)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long", stop=hprice + syminfo.mintick)
if (se)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="Short", stop=lprice - syminfo.mintick)

// Dynamic exit conditions for Long and Short trades
exitPrice_Long_A = strategy.position_avg_price - 40 * syminfo.mintick
exitPrice_Long_B = hprice + syminfo.mintick

exitPrice_Short_A = strategy.position_avg_price + 40 * syminfo.mintick
exitPrice_Short_B = lprice - syminfo.mintick

// Determine exit conditions based on the above calculations
exitConditionLong_A = le and (strategy.position_avg_price - (hprice + syminfo.mintick) >= 40 * syminfo.mintick)
exitConditionLong_B = le and not exitConditionLong_A

exitConditionShort_A = se and (lprice - syminfo.mintick - strategy.position_avg_price >= 40 * syminfo.mintick)
exitConditionShort_B = se and not exitConditionShort_A

// Execute exits based on conditions
if (exitConditionLong_A)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long A", "Long", stop=exitPrice_Long_A, comment="Exit Long Condition A")
else if (exitConditionLong_B)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long B", "Long", stop=exitPrice_Long_B, comment="Exit Long Condition B")

if (exitConditionShort_A)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short A", "Short", stop=exitPrice_Short_A, comment="Exit Short Condition A")
else if (exitConditionShort_B)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short B", "Short", stop=exitPrice_Short_B, comment="Exit Short Condition B")
```